# Invalid object name error for temporary table defined in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have written a stored procedure which executes a stored procedure and the result it gets has to be stored in a local temporary table. The Stored procedure gets created without giving any errors. But when I try to execute stored procedure, it returns the error that the temporary table is invalid object name.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE .dbo.CalulateETFWeights
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@CURR_DATE varchar(255),
@ETF_DATE datetime
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

--Select max(ETF_DATE) into @ETF_DATE from .dbo.ETF_LIST_V --where ETF_LOAD_DATE = @CURR_DATE

-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT TqaSecCode, GlobalSecurity, Cusip
into #tempetftable
from .map.v_get_tqa_security where cusip in (select distinct ETF_CUSIP from .dbo.ETF_LIST_V where ETF_LOAD_DATE = 'Mon Jun 17 14:15:09 BST 2019')


Insert into #tempPriceTable
exec .tqaif.sp_get_ds_price_usd
    @sourceTable = '#tempetftable',
    @startDate = '20181219',
    @endDate = '20181219',
    @frequency = 'D'


Insert into .dbo.ETFComponentWeights

Select 
    C.ETF_CUSIP as W_CAL_CUSIP,
    C.STK_IDX as W_CAL_COMP,
    C.STK_QUANT as W_CAL_SHARES,
    CP.VALUE as W_CAL_PRICE,
    (C.STK_QUANT  * CP.VALUE_) as W_CAL_MVAL,
    (C.STK_QUANT * CP.VALUE_)/SUM(C.STK_QUANT * CP.VALUE) over (partition by C.ETF_CUSIP) as W_CAL_WEIGHT,
    @ETF_DATE as W_CAL_DATE

from .dbo.ETF_COMP_V C
    inner join (Select E.CUSIP, P.Value_ from #tempPriceTable P inner join #tempetftable E on P.TqaSecCode = E.TqaSecCode) CP
    on C.ETF_CUSIP = CP.CUSIP
```

So the error I get is
        Invalid object name '#tempPriceTable'.

I don't understand why is this not working? Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong here? and why the #tempetftable works fine. But #tempPriceTable here is not working in this scenario?

Comment: `#tempPriceTable` is not defined in the SP, It's `#tempetftable` table

Comment: They are two separate temporary tables. and I thought temporary tables are simply created by using insert into #temp statement. that's why I have not used create table #tempPriceTable

Comment: `SELECT . . . INTO` will create the table, while `INSERT INTO` won't. That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax:

```
SELECT TqaSecCode, GlobalSecurity, Cusip
into #tempetftable
```

creates a new temp table and then inserts data into this new table.

Syntax:

```
Insert into #tempPriceTable
exec .tqaif.sp_get_ds_price_usd
```

is a regular "insert into" statement, which adds rows to existing table.
To use this syntax you need to create an empty temp table with correct schema beforehand.
So you need to do something like:

```
CREATE TABLE #tempPriceTable (your schema)
Insert into #tempPriceTable
exec .tqaif.sp_get_ds_price_usd
```